# In Typescript, how can I return the inferred type given a type check and discriminated union?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a discriminated union type, such as:

```
interface State {
    mode: {type: 'mode1'; someProperty: number;} | {type: 'mode2'; differentProperty: string;}
}
```

And I'm working with a wrapper that has that type as a generic parameter in context:

```
const myWrapper = Wrapper<State>();
```

I would like to create a function on the wrapper that is able to narrow the scope of the 'mode' property's type and return it in context. e.g.

```
myWrapper.when(m => m.type === "mode1").do(m => console.log(m.someProperty)
```

So that the 'when' method returns the type inferred given the check supplied as an argument.

Any hints?

### Update

My last code was fairly conceptual, so there's no 'implementation' of `Wrapper` that I can share...

But with some more play, I found a better way to describe what I'm looking for...

Consider the following code:

```
type FooBar = { type: 'foo' } | { type: 'bar' };
const fooBars: FooBar[] = [];
const foos = fooBars.filter(b => b.type == "foo");
```

The problem here is that type inference resolves `foos` as `{ type: 'foo' } | { type: 'bar' }` even though we know they will all be `foo`.

It would be cool if TS could infer the return type of the filter function since we are checking on a union type's discriminator.

But I guess that's not possible without casting.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question fully, but probably, you can try using `as`. Something like `.when((x: Type): ReturnType => {...})`

Comment: Sure I can cast it to whatever I want, but then I would have to specify the type I want explicitly. e.g. `as {type: 'mode1'; someProperty: number;}`, or create a type alias for it and use that.

The idea is to only need to provide the logic for the correct type inference, without need a reference to the actual type up front.

Comment: If you have a union type you also need type guards... And since your union type is predefined, why can't you predefine your type guards?

Comment: Can you post more details of your `Wrapper<T>` type?  That's where the issue is.  I'm surprised that `Wrapper.when()`'s callback operates on a parameter of the `mode` property of `T` instead of on a parameter of type `T` itself.

Comment: You can extract filter predicate to type guard `function isFoo(item: FooBar): item is Foo { return item.type === 'foo'; }`